# Not able to see old launch files in run configurations in eclipse oxyge

Tags: eclipse

Recently I update my eclipse to Oxygen, in old eclipse I saved maven launch files in each project folder/.settings and I was able to see these maven launch files in run configuration in eclipse, now in oxygen, I'm able to see only launch files from workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core\.launches . Is there a way to make visible in run configurations launch files from project folder/.settings ?